# Trying converting old Java function nested for loops to RxJava style

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am trying to convert an old java code with so many nested filtering into RxJava style.

```
class DownloadTicket{

private interface TicketRepository{
    Single<List<String>> getTickets();
}


public void filterAndDownloadTickets(TicketRepository ticketsRepository){

    ticketsRepository.getTickets().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).doOnSuccess(journeyResultDtos -> {

        for (JourneyResultDto journeyResultDto : journeyResultDtos) {

            for (TicketBookingDto ticketBookingDto : journeyResultDto.getBookings().values()) {

                if (ticketBookingDto.getBookingUuid().equals(bookingUUID)) {

                    for (TicketFileDto ticketFileDto : journeyResultDto.getTicketFiles().values()) {

                        if (ticketFileDto.getFileType().contains(CompanionActivity.FILETYPE_MOT)) {
                            // Here I'd like to receive the filer list, so I can perform some operation on it.
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

As you can see function **filterAndDownloadTickets** contain too many nested **for** loops, I tried different ways of converting the code into RxJava using flatMap, filter etc. But, I haven't still made any breakthrough.

Can anyone help me in converting this into RxJava?

Comment: RxJava? You're iterating a collection. You're looking for a collection stream api, not RxJava. Maybe use Kotlin, it has collection stream operators built in?

Comment: just to note everything downstream of your `observeOn` will be on the main thread

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of your data model but something like this should work.  Basically you want to flatmap when you have a list of objects and you want to emit each object in the list, then you want to map when you want to convert and object to one of it's child objects, finally you want to filter for your if conditions.

```
ticketsRepository
.getTickets()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.flatMap(journeyResultDtos -> journeyResultDtos) //map the list to into an Observable which emits every item in the list
.map(journeyResultDto -> journeyResultDto.getBookings()) //Map to the list of bookings
.flatMap(ticketBookingDtos -> ticketBookingDtos)//map the list to into an Observable which emits every item in the list
.filter(ticketBookingDto -> ticketBookingDto.getBookingUuid().equals(bookingUUID)) //apply first if condition
.map(ticketBookingDto -> journeyResultDto.getTicketFiles()) //Map to ticket files
.flatMap(ticketFileDtos -> ticketFileDtos)//map the list to into an Observable which emits every item in the list
.filter(ticketFileDto -> ticketFileDto.getFileType().contains(CompanionActivity.FILETYPE_MOT))//Apply second if
.subscribe(ticketFileDto -> {
//handle the object
});
```